# IntelliJ remote debug gradle project can't attach sources

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm having trouble getting IntelliJ to recognize which source files correspond to the thing I'm trying to attach a debugger to.  The project in question is a Gradle project running locally, using Java 1.7.  (EDIT: I'm actually also running that project from within IntelliJ, and that's also what's building it.  It's a Gretty task defined in the project's build.gradle file.  I'm passing

> `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5006`

to the JVM to open the debugging port.)

I can tell that the debugger is attaching to the process correctly since I get the "Connected to the target VM" message.  But breakpoints do not get the checkmark, and they aren't hit during execution.  (EDIT: This is *leading me to believe* that the sources aren't being attached -- The debugger is attaching to a process successfully, and I have reason to believe that process is the one I want since I'm using JVM arguments on it to open the debugging port, but it appears to me that the IDE doesn't recognize what source files correspond to the running code.)

The other person who works on this code does not seem to have this issue.  He's on an older version of IntelliJ.  His "use module classpath" dropdown has a `<whole project>` option and mine does not (though it does have `<no module>` -- is that the same?).  Unsure which version of IJ he's on specifically; I'm on Ultimate 2018.3.

I'm sure that I need to include more information than this, but due to my unfamiliarity with Gradle as a build/run tool and with how remote debugging works in general, I don't know what information I'm missing -- of course I will provide it as soon as someone asks me for it.

BIG EDIT (and probably the real answer here): I have a feeling I'm attaching to Gradle itself rather than the task.  If I choose Run -> Attach to Process, the dialog shows me "45039 org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon (5006)".

Comment: 1. For debugging IDE uses classpath of the module specified in mentioned `use module classpath` option. 2. Debugger uses the information from the compiled classes in [module's compiler output directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/paths-tab.html#9716f982). Do you use IDE builder (Build | Build Project action)? Also clarify the problem. The header says IDE fails to attach the sources, but description says breakpoints do not get checkmarks.

Comment: @Andrey I'm not 100% sure what action is being used to build the project, because I'm doing it implicitly.  I'm not explicitly clicking on anything that causes the project to be built.  I'm using a run configuration to run a Gretty task (realized that's info that isn't in the OP -- I'll update) and that's causing the build to happen and the project to run.  I guess I'm assuming the IDE isn't attaching the sources because of the lack of checkmarks on breakpoints -- this is a little bit of a black box to me, and I'm not having luck discovering what the issue actually is.

Comment: Check `Before launch` section in Run Debug Configuration - by default there is a `Make` action which triggers IDE's builder. Is it Gradle/Maven project? `I'm assuming the IDE isn't attaching the sources` what do you mean? these are two different issues. Is the problem that breakpoints are not hit? Then please check the 1st message (make sure the classpath for the module is specified properly and the artifact that you deploy to Jetty **is [built by IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html#6db1d63c)**.